# Python Lambda Function returning KeyError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Currently trying to create a (simple) Lambda function in AWS using Python 3.8:

```
import json
import urllib3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    status_code = 200
    array_of_rows_to_return = [ ]
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    try:
        event_body = event["body"]
        payload = json.loads(event_body)
        rows = payload["data"]

        for row in rows:

            row_number = row[0]
            from_currency = row[1]
            to_currency = row[2]
            
            response = http.request('GET','https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/'+from_currency)
            response_data = response.data.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
            data = json.loads(response_data)
    
            exchange_rate_value = data['rates'][to_currency]

            output_value = [exchange_rate_value]
            row_to_return = [row_number, output_value]
            array_of_rows_to_return.append(row_to_return)

        json_compatible_string_to_return = json.dumps({"data" : array_of_rows_to_return})

    except Exception as err:
        status_code = 400
        json_compatible_string_to_return = event_body

    return {
        'statusCode': status_code,
        'body': json_compatible_string_to_return
    }
```

When I deploy/attempt to test the function from within Lambda, I receive the following error/output message:

**"errorMessage": "local variable 'event_body' referenced before assignment",
"errorType": "UnboundLocalError"**

I don't think it's my code as the instructor in the tutorial was able to run his successfully without any changes. Could someone p[lease help me determine what may be going on please?

Event_JSON below:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      0,
      "USD",
      "INR"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Update: The Lambda function now returns the following: **

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"data\": [[0, [82.920013]]]}"
}
```

However, when I am trying to test the Amazon API Gateway implementation using the sample 'Request Body', I am receiving the following output:

```
{"resource": "/", "path": "/", "httpMethod": "POST", "headers": null, "multiValueHeaders": null, "queryStringParameters": null, "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null, "pathParameters": null, "stageVariables": null, "requestContext": {"resourceId": "[removed]", "resourcePath": "/", "httpMethod": "POST", "extendedRequestId": "[requestid]", "requestTime": "27/Feb/2023:25:13:38 +0000", "path": "/", "accountId": "12345678", "protocol": "HTTP/1.1", "stage": "test-invoke-stage", "domainPrefix": "testPrefix", "requestTimeEpoch": 36018142, ....{"cognitoIdentityPoolId": null, "cognitoIdentityId": null, "apiKey": ......."cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null, "user": "1234567"}, .... "body": "{\r\n     \"data\":\r\n         [\r\n             [0,\"USD\", \"INR\"]\r\n         ]\r\n }", "isBase64Encoded": false}
```

Request body below:

```
{
     "data":
         [
             [0,"USD", "INR"]
         ]
 }
```

Comment: You already `json.loads` the event body.  Why do you do it again in the `try` block?  If "body" is not found in `event`, you'll get an exception in the first line of the `try`; it will skip to the `except` block, where it will try to use `event_body` that does not exist.  But that shouldn't happen, since you already fetched it.

Comment: Agree with @TimRoberts.  Usually `event` already comes converted into a `dict` by the lambda runtime.  Can you provide your Event JSON you are testing with?

Comment: Thanks both of you. I added that because it returned the same error message so I thought it wouldn't hurt to try and see if the error message would go away :(

Comment: Added the JSON!

Comment: FYI: i switched back the python code to the original before i started debugging. sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have `body` in your sample event.

This code was tested with your event:

```
import json
import urllib3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    status_code = 200
    array_of_rows_to_return = [ ]
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    try:
        rows = event["data"]

        for row in rows:

            row_number = row[0]
            from_currency = row[1]
            to_currency = row[2]
            
            response = http.request('GET','https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/'+from_currency)
            response_data = response.data.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
            data = json.loads(response_data)
    
            exchange_rate_value = data['rates'][to_currency]

            output_value = [exchange_rate_value]
            row_to_return = [row_number, output_value]
            array_of_rows_to_return.append(row_to_return)

        json_compatible_string_to_return = {"data" : array_of_rows_to_return}

    except Exception as err:
        status_code = 400
        json_compatible_string_to_return = event

    return {
        'statusCode': status_code,
        'body': json.dumps(json_compatible_string_to_return)
    }
```

Comment: Correction to `json.dumps()`.  I checked how they use in tutorials.

Comment: @John Wick please mark this answer as resolution to your question

Comment: Sorry, was briefly away. Just marked your answer as best answer, thanks again @Alex Chadyuk.

Just curious... what was the correction to the json.dumps that you made?

Comment: I used `json.dumps()` at the very end.  The reason is that the `event` is not a json object, it is a dict, so if you get an exception, your service will crash because the lambda will return a string `body` instead of json `body` (and it will potentially be quite hard to debug!).  Right now your lambda will always return `body` as json.

Comment: Appreciate it greatly Alex!

Comment: Probably a separate issue altogether but when I invoke this function in Amazon API Gateway, it's returning a really long json object (vs the actual conversion) for some reason:

Comment: It also makes sense to rename `json_compatible_string_to_return`, because this name will confuse you if you look at this code a year from now.  Now that I made the changes to the code, this variable is always a dictionary )))

Comment: {"resource": "/", "path": "/", "httpMethod": "POST", "headers": null, "multiValueHeaders": null, "queryStringParameters": null, "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null, "pathParameters": null, "stageVariables": null, "requestContext": {"resourceId": ..."

Comment: Yes certainly! ty

Comment: Is your API integration Type: LAMBDA_PROXY?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252173/discussion-between-alex-chadyuk-and-john-wick).